# Facebook auth.statusChange firing without user intervention

Tags: javascript, facebook

We have a website which relies on the `auth.statusChange` event from Facebook being fired when the user clicks a button which opens a popup with facebook login, so that we can log in the user once we have detected that facebook has authorized this user. This worked perfectly until some days ago where suddenly the event would be called just as the page is loaded, without any user intervention or the button being clicked. This ends up in an endless loop where the user is logged in again and again. I guess this was some change in functionality on Facebook's side. I have looked for some information about this change but I have found none. Has anyone had this issue and can recommend a workaround?